# when clicking the next button of pagination, not appearing the contents of next page in Word Press

Tags: php, wordpress

when I clicking the pagination to go to the next page, there are still the contents of first page appearing, never show the contents of second page...

after clicking, the URL of the page contained "page/2/" at last. so seems like the page is right. but contents is not right.
(please just ignore those japanese letters)

please tell me what's the problem.

functions.php

```
//Pagenation
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;//表示するページ数（５ページを表示）

     global $paged;//現在のページ値
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;//デフォルトのページ

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;//全ページ数を取得
         if(!$pages)//全ページ数が空の場合は、１とする
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }

     if(1 != $pages)//全ページが１でない場合はページネーションを表示する
     {
         echo "<div class=\"pagenation\">\n";
         echo "<ul>\n";
         //Prev：現在のページ値が１より大きい場合は表示
         if($paged > 1) echo "<li class=\"prev\"><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>Prev</a></li>\n";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                //三項演算子での条件分岐
                echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class=\"active\">".$i."</li>\n":"<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."'>".$i."</a></li>\n";
             }
         }
        //Next：総ページ数より現在のページ値が小さい場合は表示
        if ($paged < $pages) echo "<li class=\"next\"><a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next</a></li>\n";
        echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

archive.php

```
        <?php
//Pagenation 
if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use WordPress default pagination function to show on archive.php

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$translated = __( 'Page', 'mytextdomain' ); // Supply translatable string

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'before_page_number' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">'.$translated.' </span>'
) );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, but now here is other problem... it apprear right with main loop, but the same contents appear in both the second page and the first page with sub loop.